# What are the minimum system requirements for Ubuntu Snappy Core?

Tags: system-requirements, ubuntu-core

What are the minimum system requirements for [Ubuntu Snappy Core](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.cnx-software.com/2015/01/21/snappy-ubuntu-core-is-an-iot-linux-distribution-for-arm-and-x86/) *(not offical docs, I can't find any :/ )*, the minimum  requirements are:

```
Processor – 600 MHz processor (ARMv7 or greater, or x86)
System Memory – 128 MB RAM or greater (The system itself uses 40 MB RAM)
Storage – 4GB flash / storage for factory reset and system rollback
```

I am  not sure if any other specs need to be atleast something, or whether the above is accurate.

Note that ARMv6 and earlier (used on the old Raspberry Pi models etc) is not supported.

x86 is apparently supported, though a image for 15.04 does not seem to be available, though you [can get one for 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/622662/178596)

Comment: ...and how does the author know?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Wilf (I do not have 50 reputation points yet to comment :s), the official docs that back this claim are found here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/internet-of-things (scroll to "Widest range of supported devices")