# where is the 32 bit ubuntu snappy core image

Tags: 32-bit, ubuntu-core

The [Ubuntu Website](http://www.ubuntu.com/things) states that Ubuntu Core is

> Now available on a wide range of 32 and 64-bit ARM and X86 platforms.

The following page says

> 64-bit PC (AMD64) snappy image Choose this to take full advantage of
>   computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64,
>   Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made
>   by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86
>   images instead.

But there is no link to the x86 32 bit image on the page.

http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu-cdimage/vivid/

Searching around, I find this:

> Currently, no 32-bit version of Snappy Ubuntu Core is built.

Is a 32 bit X86 version of snappy core available, and if so, where is it?

Answer (score 3):

Found it here:- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/daily-preinstalled/current/ after following this discussion:-http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ubuntu.devel.snappy/117 "I want to port Ubuntu core to the x86 based hardware that I am working with. Currently I am running Ubuntu Trusty based image on it and would want to run Ubuntu snappy core on the same."

Comment: good find! Not to forget, they are super-alpha!

Comment: also I would be really interested to know how and where you are going to install it. Share you experience, please

Answer (score 0):

To my best of knowledge, 32-bit version is not available. Also, 32-bit or not, it can not be directly installed on a PC. You must use the virtualization tools. Even if you download the `snappy images` there is no way to install them directly to PC/liveCD/USB etc.

Comment: Thank you. That is the full desktop image, not the snappy core image.

Comment: how about the x86 kvm images [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/). AFAIK, currently it is only available as kvm iamge

Comment: Thanks Ron, I am already running that. I have some old x86 thin clients that I would like to try core on if I can find the 32bit image referred to on the site.

Comment: sorry for no being clear, I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into it Ron, I will keep digging.

Comment: From:- https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/ "Ubuntu Core can be installed directly on X86 or ARM devices (such as the Beaglebone Black)."  And here:- https://www.linux.com/news/embedded-mobile/mobile-linux/804659-ubuntu-snappy-leads-mobile-linux-migration-to-iot "The BeagleBone Black and Odroid-C1 SBCs are the recommended ARM development platforms, while any x86 computer or VM should do the trick on the x86 side. (Here's a Dustin Kirkland tutorial on loading Snappy on the BeagleBone Black.)

Comment: I am not sure about the 2nd link. He says snappy does not support Rpi but that is not true. The other one says x86 ARM devices/boards (such as the Beaglebone Black). If you look below that you can see "Linux users can also try Ubuntu Core locally with KVM...". The news I got from the IRC channel is that it is indeed planned to release ISOs for all but not right NOW and the 32-bit one are failing.